# Gawk - Regexp - unable to get results

Tags: regex, awk

I have a two column file named names.csv. Field 1 has names with alphabet characters in them. I am trying to find out names where a character repeats e.g. V**ii**jay (and not Vijay)

The command below works and returns all the rows in Field 1

```
gawk "$1 ~ /[a-z]/ {print $0}" names.csv
```

To meet the requirement stated above (viz. repeating characters), I have actually used the command below, which does not return any rows

```
gawk "$1 ~ /[a-z]{1,}/ {print $0}" names.csv
```

What is the correction needed to get what I am looking for?

To further elaborate, if the values in Column 1/Field 1 are Vijay, Viijay and Vijayini, i want only Viijay to be returned. That is, only values where a character ("i" in the example here) is repeated (not "recurring" as in Vijayini where the character "i" is recurring in the string but not clustered together.)

Requested sample data is:

```
Vijay 1
Viijay 2
Vijayini 3
```

and the expected output:

```
Viijay 2
```

Comment: This is not clear, please show us sample of input and expected output in your post.

Comment: If the values in Column 1 are Viijay, Vijay and Vijayini, I want only Viijay to be returned (as the  character "i" is repeated more than once). I want all values where any alphabetic character is repeated to be returned. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't reply in comments when it is clear that your question is missing important information. Edit your Q to include your small sample input and your expected output from the same input. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter, Thanks, have edited the Q, Not sure about the "question is missing important information" as the information now provided already appears partially in the very first para of the question.

Comment: If you really wrote it as indicated, rather than `gawk '$1 ~ /[a-z]{1,}/ {print $0}' names.csv`, (single quote instead of double quote), then the shell will try to expand the parameter references `$1` and `$0`, which will produce very different results, probably error messages. If you did use single quotes, your second program will recognise all three of those inputs, because `/[a-z]{1,}/` means "at least one letter", not "two letters" and much less "two of the same letter".

Comment: Why don't you use `grep`?

Answer (score 1):

As awk regex doesn't support backreferences in matching, you need to find the duplicated characters some other way. This one duplicates every character in `$1` and adds them to a variable which is then matched against the original string in, ie. `Viijay` -> `re="(VV|ii|ii|jj|aa|yy)"; if($1~re)...` (notice, that it does not test if the entry is already in `re`, you might want to consider adding some checking, more checking considerations in the comments):

```
$ awk '
{                                                 # you should test for empty $1
    re="("                                        # reset re
    for(i=1;i<=length($1);i++)                    # for each char in $1
        re=re (i==1?"":"|") (b=substr($1,i,1)) b  # generate dublicated re entry
    re=re ")"                                     # terminating )
    if($1~re)                                     # match
        print                                     # and print if needed
}' file
```

Output:

```
Viijay 2
```

Ironically or exemplarily it fails on Busybox awk—in which the backreferences can be used Ɑ:

```
$ busybox awk '$1~"(.)\\1" {print $0}' file
Viijay,2
```

Comment: That would fail if any of the characters in $1 was a regexp metacharacter.

Comment: @EdMorton True, true. Yet another check to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Since awk doesn't support backreferences in a regexp you're better off using grep or sed for this:

```
$ grep '^[^[:space:]]*\([a-z]\)\1' file
Viijay 2

$ sed -n '/^[^[:space:]]*\([a-z]\)\1/p' file
Viijay 2
```

That might be GNU-only, google to check.

With awk you'd have to do something like the following to first create a regexp that matches 2 repetitions of any character in your specific character set of `a-z`:

```
$ awk '{re=$1; gsub(/[^a-z]/,"",re); gsub(/./,"&{2}|",re); sub(/\|$/,"",re)} $1 ~ re' file
Viijay 2
```

FYI to create a regexp from `$1` that would match 2 repetitions of **any** character it contains, not just `a-z`, would be:

```
re=$1; gsub(/[^\\^]/,"[&]{2}|",re); gsub(/[\\^]/,"\\\\&{2}|",re); sub(/\|$/,"",re);
```

You have to handle `^` differently from other characters as that's the only character that has a different meaning than literal when it's the first character in a bracket expression (i.e. negation) so you have to escape it with a backslash rather than putting it inside a bracket expression to make it literal. You have to handle `\` different because `[\]` means the same as `[]` which is an unterminated bracket expression because `[` is the start but `]` is just the first character inside the bracket expression, it's not the `]` needed to terminate it.